# REST API convention for updating 2 different resources in a transaction manner

Tags: rest, api-design

I have a REST API with multiple resources. There is a scenario where two different resources should be updated. These two have one-to-one relations and must be updated transactionally.

Let's say we have `users` and `houses` resources. Which option do you prefer or think is the best way to do it? I want to know which way is less error-prone while respecting REST API design conventions.

### Option 1

Define a single endpoint that takes the user and house as body and updates it as a transaction.

```
[PUT] BASE/users/houses/update
{
  "user": {...},
  "house": {...}
}
```

### Option 2

Define two separate endpoints, each updating its own resource and handling errors separately.

```
[PUT] BASE/users/:id
{
 ...
}

[PUT] BASE/houses/:id
{
 ...
}
```

## Solution

Based on what `Evert` suggested, I have defined a virtual resource called `landlords` and the update happens transactionally. The REST endpoint is as follows:

```
[PUT] BASE/landlords
{
  "user": {...},
  "house": {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a lot of people fall in the trap that REST must be CRUD, but you're not really restricted to that.

Instead of thinking of 2 entities that need some property updated, it may be better to try to think of 'intent'. If there's a clear 'intent' that has a side-effect of multiple entities being updated, and they should succeed or fail together it's best to expose this as a single operation.

RPC aka 'submitting forms' is not anti-RESTful despite popular belief. Many complex systems will eventually have a need to have mutations separate from reading state.

That said, this pattern:

```
PUT /users/houses/update
{
  "user": {...},
  "house": {...}
}
```

Feels wrong because from a HTTP standpoint this suggest that you 'replace the "update" endpoint'. You should either:

- Try to come up with a URI / resource that represents the user and house together.
- Embrace POST for these cases.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer. I have come up with a virtual resource called the landlord. I updated the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally depends on your domain model.

You've mentioned thing such:

- There is a scenario where two different resources should be updated.
- These two have one-to-one relations and must be updated transactionally.

What the scenarios are? Why resources should be updated transactionally?
At end end what your `users` and `houses` are?

Without understanding these points no one could give a silver bullet answer.

REST itself doesn't limit you in a way you build your API and resource, as well as doesn't give you recommendations for all the cases.

Both options you've described have a place to be. There is some principles you could follow though.

- As a developer who consumes API I would prefer to make one request to achieve my needs.
- If User and House both are first-class citizens of your *domain model* and model assumes that they could be updated independently - they should have their own API for update.